# installer can't find partition, but fdisk can find them

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

My computer had two operating systems installed: Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.10.

Now, I want to update Ubuntu to 12.04. I used a USB disk to install 12.04. But the installer can't find my partitiona. `fdisk` ***can*** find them. How can I fix this?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path           Device      Class       Description
======================================================
                               system      HP 2230s (NN868PA#AB2)
/0                             bus         3037
/0/9                           memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/0                           processor   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6570  @ 2.10GHz
/0/0/1                         memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/0/3                         memory      32KiB L1 cache
/0/0/0.1                       processor   Logical CPU
/0/0/0.2                       processor   Logical CPU
/0/2                           memory      32KiB L1 cache
/0/4                           memory      2GiB System Memory
/0/4/0                         memory      SODIMM [empty]
/0/4/1                         memory      2GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
/0/100                         bridge      Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub
/0/100/2                       display     Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/2.1                     display     Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/1a                      bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
/0/100/1a.1                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
/0/100/1a.2                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
/0/100/1a.7                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1b                      multimedia  82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                      bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c.1                    bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2
/0/100/1c.1/0      wlan1       network     PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
/0/100/1c.2                    bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3
/0/100/1c.4                    bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5
/0/100/1c.5                    bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6
/0/100/1c.5/0      eth1        network     88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d                      bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.1                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1d.2                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
/0/100/1d.7                    bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1e                      bridge      82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
/0/100/1f                      bridge      ICH9M LPC Interface Controller
/0/100/1f.2        scsi0       storage     82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.2/0      /dev/sda    disk        500GB WDC WD5000BEVT-0
/0/100/1f.2/0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      48GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1f.2/0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      416GiB Extended partition
/0/100/1f.2/0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume      97GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/100/1f.2/0/2/6  /dev/sda6   volume      198GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/100/1f.2/0/2/7  /dev/sda7   volume      27GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/100/1f.2/0/2/8  /dev/sda8   volume      93GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/100/1f.2/1      /dev/cdrom  disk        CDDVDW TS-L633M
/0/1               scsi6       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0         /dev/sdb    disk        15GB STORAGE DEVICE
/0/1/0.0.0/0       /dev/sdb    disk        15GB 
/0/1/0.0.0/0/1     /dev/sdb1   volume      14GiB Windows FAT volume
/1                             power       HZ04037
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

---

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x31263125

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   102277727    51138832+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102277728   976784129   437253201    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       102277791   307078127   102400168+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       307078191   724141151   208531480+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       724142080   781459455    28658688   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       781461504   976771071    97654784   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.9 GB, 15931539456 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15193 cylinders, total 31116288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009eb92

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  Systemfile:///home/ubuntu/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202012-07-07%2010:25:40.png

/dev/sdb1   *          32    31115263    15557616    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

---

Ubuntu 12.04's installer can't find the partition in my hard disk. It only find the device - `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 1):

Pxd, boot back into your Ubuntu 10.10 installation and run this from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Alternatively, you can run `update-manager -d` from the terminal and upgrade using the GUI tool.

Either option will get you upgraded to the next latest release without losing any saved data.

Comment: Think you for your help!